# How to set up MySQL database when upload site to host?

Tags: mysql, upload, web

I'm trying to upload my web site to public host and make it live for the first time. My web site is placed on my home computer. I use XAMPP as working environment and Joomla 2.5.9.

I suppose I should do 2 things:

1. Copy all site structure with all sub folders (administrator, cache, cli, components and so on) to the host. I did it using FileZilla.
2. Set up MySQL database. I don't how to do that. I've exported all tables from my locale database to SQL file and make ZIP file as first step. After that I've opened phpMyAdmin on host and went to Database section. But, there's no "Create database" option there.

How can I set up the database on host?

Is there any other thing I should do except from 1) and 2)?

Comment: That fully depends on your host. Where exactly are you hosting your website?

Comment: you must to know the hosting server name and credentials to connect to MySQL on your hosting. Simply supply the script of local Mysql to hosting MySQL database and it will work. As @JimmyvanBeele said, it all depends on the hosting details.

Comment: Ok. I use cPanel. I've succeeded to create new database, but it has prefix, which is automatically added. It looks as: user_dbname. My locale database name is only: dbname. After I've created new database user_dbname on host, I've imported all tables from my locale database and it was ok. But, when I ran my web site the error: "Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL." comes up. What I did wrong and/or what else I should do to make it work?

Comment: Did you change your MySQL settings in your config to use the new 'user_dbname' database? If so, are you sure the database is running on localhost? Again, where are you hosting?

Comment: I host to one Russian host.

Comment: When you asked "Did you change your MySQL settings in your config to use the new 'user_dbname' database" have you meant on configuration.php file?

Comment: Could someone help with this, please?

Answer (score -1):

From phpMyAdmin, go to SQL and run the following command:

`CREATE DATABASE joomla`

Another option can be that you need to create the database and the user / pass combination from a hosting control panel like CPanel, Plesk etc.

Now enter the database and hit the import button to import your zip (with the db dump).

You also need to adapt the config file `configuration.php` to match your new host config, especially:

- $db
- $host
- $user
- $password
- $log_path
- $tmp_path

Comment: I can't create database with any name. I can create the database in this form: user_<database name>. For example: mike_myStore. I can't get rid of "mike_". The database name on my home computer is myStore. After I've created new database mike_myStore on host, I've imported all tables from my locale database myStore and it was ok. But, when I ran my web site the error: "Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL." comes up. What I did wrong and/or what else I should do to make it work?

Comment: I've opened configuration.php file and changed "public $db" item to be: mike_myStore, but the same error: "Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL." comes up. There are all locale settings. What else should I change? You've listed them, but what is $host for example? In my locale file is: localhost.

Comment: I've changed all items you'd listed, but there's still the same error. I'm not sure if $host is correct. In my case it looks like: http://11111.aaa.ru

Comment: There's also $dbprefix item. In my locale configuration.php it's: aaaaa_. But, database name on host is: aaa11111_dbname.

Comment: Could someone help with this, please?